# Node js closures need pushing to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I have a problem that my code wont return the array which has been pushed data into, I figured out last night it was something about closures, I researched them and I don't really get them. All the examples are using addeventlistener.
I know I have to somehow wait until my push is done because this is async.

```
app.post("/search", function(req, res){
    var test = []
    for (var key in req.body.movie){
        Movie.find({title: "Gotham"}, function(err, foundMovie){
            test.push(foundMovie)
        })
    }
    console.log(test)
    res.render("index")
});
```

Comment: The array `test` will be empty by the time `console.log` happens as none of the `Movie.find` have yet done their work (and push items into the array). You have to use the array after all the `Movie.find` finished their jobs.

Comment: Movie.find() is probably asynchronous. So you have to include the code that returns the result inside the callback `function(err, foundMovie)` .

Comment: Look into `async/await` and `Promise.all()`

Comment: As an addition to all previous comments, you execute exactly the same `.find()` query in a loop = multiple times, which is not efficient.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I get that I have to wait, I found that out using setinterval, but how would I wait for the function to be done? I could possibly add a length check between foundmovies and req.body.movies then call the log function, but other then that I have no idea

Comment: @KeeganRiley You could make them as [**promises**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). I haven't use them yet but they seem like the right approach to this.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB/Mongoose operations are asynchronous. A possible fix for your problem would be to use `async/await` like so.

```
app.post("/search", async function(req, res){
    var test = []
    for (var key in req.body.movie){
        let foundMovie = await Movie.find({title: "Gotham"})
        test.push(foundMovie)
    }
    console.log(test)
    res.render("index")
});
```

You will need to use newer version of Node for async/await to work. :)

Also never execute DB queries in loops.